# firefox ajax loads form, cant serialize elements from that form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

You can see a live version of this on http://team.prteamsales.com/orderForm.php.  when asked for an formId enter BroadRunTrack2013.  Then try to add an item to cart. make sure to put info in the player name stuff.  just put in garbage for now.  choose the Runners Hat and pick color/size and qty then click complete.

I have a page that contains a button with id (addToCart).  When the user clicks on this button a dialog window will appear.  The contents of this dialog window is a form (With id #theStuff) that is on addToCart.php.  so when the user clicks addToCart,  ajax calls addToCart.php and loads the form elements into the dialog window.   The user then fills out all the elements of the form.  When the user is done, he clicks complete.  The complete button function of the modal does 2 things.  1) serialize the data in the #theStuff form, and the post it via ajax to a processor.php page.

The problem i am running into, is that serialization of #theStuff is an empty POST.

orderForm.php

the jquery

```
$('.addToCart').click(function () {
        //modal dialog settings....
        saveDialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
            "Complete": function () {
                console.log($("form#theStuff"));
                var datastring = $("form#theStuff").serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "PostToCart.php",
                    data: datastring,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "getCartSum.php",
                            success: function (rez) {
                                $('#cartSum').html(rez);
                            }
                        });
                        var saveDialog = $('#dialogAddToCart');
                        saveDialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
                            "Back to Order Form": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                        $('#dialogAddToCart').dialog('option', 'title', 'Request Complete');
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", this.parentNode).hide();
                        $('#dialogAddToCart').html(result);
                    }
                });
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });
        $('#dialogAddToCart').dialog('open');
        var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
        var formId = $('#formId').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addToCart.php",
            data: "itemId=" + itemId + "&formId=" + formId,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#dialogAddToCart').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

original form below, has nothing to do with the current problem. this is the page the user starts off on

```
 <form id='orderData' name='orderData' method='POST' action='#'>
 <table align='right' class='playerInfo' width='60%'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerName' id='playerName'></td>
    <th>Address</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerAddress' id='playerAddress'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>City</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerCity' id='playerCity'></td>
    <th>State</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerState' id='playerState'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Zip Code</th>
    <Td><input type='text' name='playerZip' id='playerZip'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerPhone' id='playerPhone'></td>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <td><input type='text' name='playerEmail' id='playerEmail'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
....//some other inputs

 <td class='borderRight' ><input type='button' class='addToCart' id='addToCart_" . $packages[$a]['id'] . "' value='Add to Cart'></td>
 </form>
```

addToCart.php

```
  <form id='theStuff' name='theStuff' method='POST' action='#'>

 echo "<td class='dialog'><select id='item[" . $row['itemId'] . "][size]' name='item[" . $row['itemId'] . "][size]' class='pkgVerify'>
                                            <option value=''></option>";
            foreach ($sizes as $value)
            {
                            echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $value . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></td>";
  echo "<input type='text' id='item[" . $row['itemId'] . "][nameOnBack]' name='item[" . $row['itemId'] . "][nameOnBack]'></td>";

   .....//a bunch of other elements.
```

PostToCart.php

```
 <?php

 print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: What does it mean that it "cant find" the form data? What is the error? Have you tried debugging with firebug, stepping through and seeing if the values match what you'd expect at each step?

Comment: yea, the POST in firefox firebug is empty.  print_r($_POST) on the next page is an empty array.  I am assuming jquery tries to serialize #theStuff, and cant find it.

Comment: so the value of datastring on the line after you set it doesn't match what you expect? does console.log($("form#theStuff")) produce an empty result? that would help confirm whether jquery can find it

Comment: I get a long list of things in the console log, but i cant tell where i find what the values of the elements are.   there is an object there called form#theStuff and a huge list of things in a heirarchy.

Comment: that means jquery is finding the form successfully, but maybe not serializing properly. compare the value of `datastring` between two browsers and see if they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. Note I assume you have declared your itemId var before at some stage;

```
    // Javascript
var form = $("form#theStuff").serializeArray();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "addToCart.php",
    data: {
        form: form,
        itemID: itemId
    },
            dataType: "json"
    success: function(result) {
        $('#dialogAddToCart').html(result);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});


// PHP;
$form = $_POST['form'];
$itemID = $_POST['itemID'];
```

Maybe adding dataType will help.

Comment: the form#theStuff data values are a result of addToCart.php being loaded.   addToCart.php is a form with elements.  addToCart.php is called, form loads,  user fills out form, click "Complete" on modal window, i then try to serialize theStuff form, and get nothing...

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the flow of the application. Perhaps you could post more of your code? Perhaps in a jsfiddle.

Comment: its all on a private server and i cant use fiddle ajax stuff.   let me edit question. hopefully i can explain better.

Comment: Okay, can you add your Javascript which does the final post to processor.php?

Comment: i will tomorrow,  i am at home now.  code is on dev server at work.

Comment: however its just an ajax call, and processor inserts stuff into db.  long before any of that, if i do print_r($_POST) on the processor page  i get an empty array.

Comment: You need to check in your javascript before you do your ajax post that the vars of the form are actually in the variable you send in your ajax using a console.log right before the ajax.

Comment: I get a long list of things in the console log, but i cant tell where i find what the values of the elements are.

Comment: Okay so you are not getting the right things to post in your Ajax. I think what is happening is you are getting a whole jQuery element, like a form and trying to post that, which doesn't work. My guess is that Chrome realises this is a form element and serialises it before sending it, where as other browsers may not be as smart. What we need to see is the HTML of the loaded form, and your javascript which takes that data, and then posts it to processor.php. The code you have posted is the step before your problems, and is not helpful.

Comment: @bart2puck, this is not the full code, and its not formatted very nicely. Either way, I did get all the vars when posting to PostToCart.php on Firefox; http://imgur.com/m2HiWKI

Comment: same here. the jquery ajax really needs error handlers to debug what is happening.

Comment: Agreed, and everything just needs to be formatted a little nicer. Perhaps split you ajax calls in to discreet functions.

Comment: Nick, did the next dialog window show you that it was added, or did you get an error about POST key not being present?  Im wondering if some of my tinkering today may have made it work.  that must be it, because it is working for me now too.

Comment: nick, can you link somewhere to help me format the code nicer?

Comment: @bart2puck all I mean is indenting everything correctly and having all the brackets. A good place to 'beautify' JS is http://jsbeautifier.org/ however you should be doing this as you code. I understand if its just because you copied it into stackoverflow but it would be considerate to us to format it nicely so we can help you easier. Also, a good place to post larger snippets of code is http://jsfiddle.net/ and if you can get a working example going there, even better. Either way, you've figured everything out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start by learning how to debug using Firebug and Chrome's developer tools, setting breakpoints and stepping through code one line at a time, making sure all the variable values match what you expect. Using this method, I was able to determine that jquery is, in fact, finding the form, and serializing it properly in Firefox, so you can rule that out and stop trying to find a solution to a problem where it doesn't exist.

Besides that, make sure you are checking the results of the ajax calls with error handling functions. I'd recommend something like the following

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(status+":"+error+":"+xhr.responseText);
}
```

You aren't validating the results of the success data either, making sure that it was actually successful.

Comment: i appreciate the response however, the entirety of this question was because the variables were not matching what i expected, and needed assistance in resolving it.  I believe sometime between this original post and the time you checked i unknowingly resolved the issue.  thank you for the error checking code. i will use it in the future.